# How to publish dotnet console app in single file for linux-bionic-arm64

Tags: .net

I'm trying to build a console app from command line:

```
dotnet "build" "/path/to/MyApp.csproj" "--configuration" "Release" "--runtime" "linux-bionic-arm64"
```

And the content in csproj is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;linux-bionic-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MD5" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine" Version="2.0.0-beta4.22272.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But I get the following error:

```
MSBuild version 17.4.8+6918b863a for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.109/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5150,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "/path/to/MyApp/obj/net7.0/linux-bionic-arm64/singlefilehost" because it was not found. [/path/to/MyApp.csproj]
Build FAILED.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.109/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5150,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "/path/to/MyApp/obj/net7.0/linux-bionic-arm64/singlefilehost" because it was not found. [/path/to/MyApp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.94
```

After some experiments, I find that it works without `PublishSingleFile=true`.

It seems that the app host for [linux-bionic-arm64 is distributed with sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/blob/v7.0.109/src/redist/targets/GenerateBundledVersions.targets#L161), why the `PublishSingleFile` option doesn't work with `linux-bionic-arm64`?

Comment: Having the same problem when attempting to use `dotnet publish`, but with `linux-arm64` instead of `linux-bionic-arm64`. As you mentioned, removing `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` helps.